# Custum Toggle open by default (Divi Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle, divi

i am NOT using the standard divi (WP Tehem) toggle module but the custum toggle code after this offical ET guide (https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/2-ways-to-create-custom-show-more-toggles-in-divi)

I am also not using a button as a toggle trigger, but an normal text module. So i am using this code:

```
<style>
  .et-show-more-content {
  display:none;
}
.et-fb .et-show-more-content {
  display:block;
}
.et-show-more-toggle0 {
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
<script>(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function()


{
        $('.et-show-more-toggle0').on('click', function(e) {
           
            $(e.target).closest('.et-show-more-container').children('.et-show-more-content').slideToggle("300");
   $(this).toggleClass('et-show-more-toggle0_active');
          if ($(this).hasClass('et-show-more-toggle0_active')) {
                                $(this).text('vorwort');
                    $(this).css('text-align','left');
                    $(this).css('color', '#4d4b40');
                                       
             } else {
                $(this).text('vorwort');
                       $(this).css('text-align','left');
                $(this).css('color', '#dc1250');
     
         
       
            }
         
           
        });
    });
})(jQuery);</script>
```

**My question is: how can I make the toggle module display open when the page is loading.**
I tried deleting .et-show-more-content oder et-fb .et-show-more-content but that did not work.

Thank your very much!

Comment: Your question is difficult for people to answer. You should post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little difficult to under but yes you have shared divi resources link and I've tried that layout after downloading and it's working fine for me so, please follow the steps which they explained and if you don't want to use button then simply can you make that button as a simple text using our custom CSS with specific class if only that button cause the issue.